# Want write-lock in a database row (Postgress), in order to not allow to modify the row by another transaction (from any of the pod)

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I want write-lock in a database row, in order to not allow to modify the row by another transaction (from any of the pod in clustered environment).
I am facing issue in clustered environment, where we have 3 application pods. Tried to use **@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)** but that is not working as well.
findById doesnt lock the row and return same entity to all the instances

Sample Code is:

```
@Transactional
    public boolean updateLicenseCount(String serviceId, String tenantId){
        LicenseCountId licenseCountId = new LicenseCountId(tenantId, serviceId);
        Optional<LicenseCountEntity> licenseCountEntity = springJpaLicenseCountRepository.findById(licenseCountId);
        
        //Perform some operaion on licenseCountEntity
        //save the licenseCountEntity

    }

    //This is what I have in springJpaLicenseCountRepository 
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    public Optional<LicenseCountEntity> findById(LicenseCountId licenseCountId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If when you update a row and do not commit the process, then other transactions will be able to update that row. If you want to lock the row before doing the update you can do so using `select ... for update`.
*You can not prevent other sessions from reading that row, and frankly, that doesn't make sense either.*
For example:

```
select * from users where user_id = 5 for update
```

after this command, so after this select another transaction never can update this row before you update;
after your update on this row, this row will be unlocked.

`FOR SHARE`  - mode is used when we need to read a row, but no other transaction is permitted to change it.
`FOR KEY SHARE`  - mode permits a change of a row, but only in its non-key fields. In particular, PostgreSQL automatically uses this mode when checking foreign keys.